# Collapsing matrix into columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a 2D matrix where the № of columns is always a multiple of 3 (e.g. `250×27`) - due to a repeating organisation of the results (`A,B,C`, `A,B,C`, `A,B,C`, and so forth). I wish to reshape this matrix to create a new matrix with 3 columns - each containing the aggregated data for each type (`A,B,C`) (e.g. `2250×3`).

So in a matrix of `250×27`, all the data in columns `1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25` would be merged to form the first column of the resulting reshaped matrix.

The second column in the resulting reshaped matrix would contain all the data from columns `2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26` - and so forth.

Is there a simple way to do this in MATLAB? I only know how to use `reshape` if the columns I wanted to merge were adjacent (`1,2,3,4,5,6`) rather than non-adjacent (`1,4,7,10,13,16`) etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shameless steal from [@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40508999/1085062):

```
B = reshape( permute( reshape(A,size(A,1),3,[]), [1,3,2]), [], 3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Let `A` be your matrix. You can save every third column in one matrix like:
(Note that you don't have to save them as matrices separately but it makes this example easier to read).

```
A = rand(27); %as test
B = A(:,1:3:end);
C = A(:,2:3:end);
D = A(:,3:3:end);
```

Then you use reshape:

```
B = reshape(B,[],1);
C = reshape(C,[],1);
D = reshape(D,[],1);
```

And finally put it all together:

```
A = [B C D];
```

Comment: I suppose it could be made more compact by skipping the middle block and using `B(:)` in the final block, but overall this seems like the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can just treat every set of columns as a single item and do three reshapes together. This should do the trick:

[save as "reshape3.m" file in your Matlab folder to call it as a function]

```
function out = reshape3(in)
    [~,C]=size(in); % determine number of columns
    if mod(C,3) ~=0 
        error('ERROR: Number of rows must be a multiple of 3')
    end

    R_out=numel(in)/3; % number of rows in output

    % Reshape columns 1,4,7 together as new column 1, column 2,5,8 as new col 2 and so on
    out=[reshape(in(:,1:3:end),R_out,1), ...
        reshape(in(:,2:3:end),R_out,1), ...
        reshape(in(:,3:3:end),R_out,1)];
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose you have a 3x6 matrix `A`

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6;6 5 4 3 2 1;2 3 4 5 6 7]
A =

     1     2     3     4     5     6
     6     5     4     3     2     1
     2     3     4     5     6     7
```

you extract the size of the matrix

```
b =size(A)
```

and then extract each third column for a single row

```
c1 = A((1:b(1)),[1:3:b(2)])
c2 = A((1:b(1)),[2:3:b(2)])
c3 = A((1:b(1)),[3:3:b(2)])
```

and put them in one matrix

```
A_result = [c1(:) c2(:) c3(:)]

A_result =

     1     2     3
     6     5     4
     2     3     4
     4     5     6
     3     2     1
     5     6     7
```

Comment: Though it works, it does not appear to add much to the existing answers and comments.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin There were no answers when I saw this question , so  just shared another way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

```
nRows = size(matrix, 1);
nBlocks = size(matrix, 2) / 3;
matrix = reshape(matrix, [nRows 3 nBlocks]);
matrix = permute(matrix, [1 3 2]);
matrix = reshape(matrix, [nRows * nBlocks 1 3]);
matrix = reshape(matrix(:), [nRows * nBlocks 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 minute take on it:

```
rv  = @(x) x(:);
ind = 1:3:size(A,2);
B   = [rv(A(:,ind)) rv(A(:,ind+1)) rv(A(:,ind+2))];
```

saves a few ugly `reshape`s, may be a bit slower though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **Image Processing Toolbox**, [**`im2col`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) is a very handy solution:

```
out = im2col(A,[1 4], 'distinct').'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try [Matlab function mat2cell](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html), I think this form is allowed.

```
X is the "start matrix"    
C = mat2cell(X, [n], [3, 3, 3]); %n is the number of rows, repeat "3" as many times as you nedd

%extract every matrix
C1 = C{1,1}; %first group of 3 columns
C2 = C{1,2}; %second group of 3 columns 
%repeat for all your groups

%join the matrix with vertcat
Cnew = vertcat(C1,C2,C3); %join as many matrix n-by-3 as you have
```

Comment: Will not work (most obvious hint is that C1==C2), also it is generally a bad idea to use cells to go from 1 matrix shape to another as this is quite inefficient.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin C1 = C2 is obviously my fault in wrinting index (updated), and thank you. Why Matlab in-built function are considered quite inefficient?

Comment: inbuilt functions in general are fine. But cell is a much more versatile datatype than matrix. As such it should not be a surprise that usually it is more efficient to operate on the matrix, rather than converting it to a cell, operating on the cell, and converting it to a matrix. -- For small problems efficiency may not be a concern, but in that case I would still argue that it is best practice for code clarity, to stick to matrices unless there is a compelling reason not to.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin thank you for complete and fast answer :)