# How to dynamically reshape matrix block-wise?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Let's say I have `A = [1:8; 11:18; 21:28; 31:38; 41:48]` Now I would like to move everything from column 4 onward to the row position. How do I achieve this?

```
A =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28
    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38
    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48
```

to

```
A2 =

     1     2     3     4    
    11    12    13    14    
    21    22    23    24    
    31    32    33    34    
    41    42    43    44    
     5     6     7     8
    15    16    17    18
    35    36    37    38
    45    46    47    48
```

`reshape` doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40506417/1085062)  is related (if not duplicate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach with [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) -

```
reshape(permute(reshape(a,size(a,1),4,[]),[1,3,2]),[],4)
```

Making it generic, we could introduce the number of columns as a parameter. Hence, let `ncols` be that one. So, the solution becomes -

```
ncols = 4
reshape(permute(reshape(a,size(a,1),ncols,[]),[1,3,2]),[],ncols)
```

Sample run -

```
>> a
a =
    20    79    18    82    27    23    59    66    46    21    48    95
    96    83    46    49    34    88    23    42    17    27    15    54
    11    88    34    92    23    62    86    56    32    32    91    54
>> reshape(permute(reshape(a,size(a,1),4,[]),[1,3,2]),[],4)
ans =
    20    79    18    82
    96    83    46    49
    11    88    34    92
    27    23    59    66
    34    88    23    42
    23    62    86    56
    46    21    48    95
    17    27    15    54
    32    32    91    54
```

More info on the [intuition behind such a **General idea for `nd` to `nd` transformation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/), which even though originally was meant for NumPy/Python, extends to any programming paradigm in general.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Matrix indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)!

```
B=[A(:,1:4);A(:,5:8)]
```

In a loop...

```
for ii=0:floor(size(A,2)/4)-1
   B([1+5*ii:5*(ii+1)],:)=A(:,[1+4*ii:4*(ii+1)] );
end
```

Comment: Can I do this dynamically without using loop? 'A' might have few thousands of columns, I need to cut it down every 4 column.

Comment: @Jdane there you go, but as usual, Divakar has a better answer!

Comment: thanks for the help! you gave me one more option in solving this!

Answer (score 2):

One more... perhaps unoptimized way would be to decompose the matrix into cells row-wise, transpose the cell array then concatenate everything back together:

```
B = cell2mat(mat2cell(A, size(A, 1), 4 * ones((size(A, 2) / 4), 1)).');
```

The above first uses [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to decompose the matrix into non-overlapping cells.  Each cell has the same number of rows as `A` but the total number of columns is 4 and there are exactly `size(A, 2) / 4` of them.  As such, we need to indicate a vector of ones where each element is 4 and there are `size(A, 2) / 4` of these to tell us the number of columns for each cell.  This creates a row-wise cell array and so we transpose this cell array and merge all of the cells together into one final matrix with [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).