# How to reshape a matrix in matlab were you want the columns to fill in from other column than reshape uses?

Tags: matlab

I have a 50000x20 matrix I want to reshape into a 500000x2 matrix but I want my columns not to fill from the next ones but staggered. Below you find an example of what I need. I was thinking about making a for loop to do the reshaping manually. Is there a more efficient way?

Example:

```matlab
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6
   1,2,3,4,5,6
   1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

reshape would give

```
[1,4
 1,4
 1,4
 2,5
 2,5
 2,5
 3,6
 3,6
 3,6]
```

I want

```
[1,2
 1,2
 1,2
 3,4
 3,4
 3,4
 5,6
 5,6
 5,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Manual for loop reshape vs vectorized approach from [How to dynamically reshape matrix block-wise?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40508999/5000841) on 2023b

```matlab
clear all

A=reshape(1:50000*20,50000,20);

tic
nrow = size(A,1);
ncol = size(A,2);
C = zeros(numel(A)/2,2);
for i = 1:ncol/2
    start_row = (i-1)*nrow + 1;
    end_row = i*nrow;
    col1 = (i-1)*2+1;
    col2 = (i-1)*2+2;
    C(start_row:end_row,1:2) = A(:,col1:col2);
end
toc

tic
ncols = 2;
E = reshape(permute(reshape(A,size(A,1),ncols,[]),[1,3,2]),[],ncols);
toc
```

```
Elapsed time is 0.002025 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000786 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to just rearrange the columns by odd & even and then reshape the result into two columns. E.g.,

```
result = reshape(A(:,[1:2:end,2:2:end]),[],2);
```